# Can a group $G=(S, \ast)$ contain less "elements" than $S$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

I used "elements" in the title because I know that technically $(S, \cdot)$ is a set with two elements.

Consider the set $S=\{e, a_1, a_2, a_3, ... \}$ and define the operation $\ast:S \times S \to S$ by $x \ast y = e$ for every $x, y \in S$. Then $\ast$ is a binary associative operation on $S$, and it is not difficult to show that the group axioms hold for $(S, \ast)$. But in this group, every element of $S$ behave as the identity; and since the identity is unique, we must $e=a_1=a_2=a_3=\cdots$ and thus $G$ is the trivial group of order $1$, even though in the set $S$ we have $e \not = a_1 \not = a_2 \not = a_3 \not = \cdots$ .

Is my argument above correct? If so, I have a couple of follow-up questions:

$1)$ Is there some terminology which distinguishes between the elements of the set $S$ and the "elements" of the group $G$?

$2)$ Why do we seem to never worry about this in group theory books? In every book that I've seen, we seem to define a set of $n$ elements, define a binary operation on it, and assume that the group also has $n$ "elements".

**EDIT:** Sorry if the title confused anybody, I had "more" when it should've been "less".

Comment: Your argument shows that no matter how we set up the binary operation, we can always throw out all the extra elements to get what we would call normally a group, I think.

Comment: @MorganRodgers While trying to answer question $2$ I realized that you are right and I wanted to delete this question (before it got an answer). But just to address $1$, in my textbook (Dummit & F) a group is defined as an ordered pair and ordered pairs are sets with two elements.

Comment: @MorganRodgers Hmm I don't think of ordered pairs intuitively as sets, but I thought formally the ordered pair $(a, b)$ is defined as the set $\{\{a\}, \{a, b\} \}$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair#Kuratowski's_definition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say you have two distinct elements $x,e\in S$, where $x\neq e$. If $(S,\cdot)$ were to satisfy the group axioms then we would have
$$x = x\cdot e = e.$$ which is a contradiction. Actually, you should rewrite $\cdot$ in function notation:
$$\cdot(x,e) = x$$
$$\cdot(x,e) = e$$
So $\cdot$ as a function is not well defined. (Does it send $(x,e)$ to $x$ or to $e$? These are different results by assumption.) Thus it is not a binary operation on $S$.

Answer (score 2):

Your binary operation $*$ does *not* satisfy the group axioms (assuming that $e,a_1,a_2,\dots$ are all distinct elements of $S$)!  In particular, it has no identity element: there is no element $x\in S$ such that $x*y=y*x=y$ for all $y$.  Indeed, it is impossible to have $x*y=y$ unless $y=e$.

More generally, the distinction between elements and "elements" you are trying to make does not exist.  Your argument, if correct, would simply give a contradiction, since you have both $e=a_1$ and $e\neq a_1$, for instance.